# Error in running Random Forest Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to implement the Random Forest Classifier in the python but it shows a value error. The example code is:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("0.5-1.csv")
df.head()

X = df[['wavelength', 'phase velocity']]
y = df['shear wave velocity']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

print (len(X_train),len(X_test),len(y_train),len(y_test))

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print (rf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\My Drive\ANN\test\0.5-1\0.5-1_tunecode.py", line 23, in <module>
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\sadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 275, in fit
    y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
  File "C:\Users\sadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 478, in _validate_y_class_weight
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\sadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

The failure occurs on:

```
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Here is my sample data:]

Comment: Please share the sample data file.

Comment: Please don't share whole csv data on google spreadsheet. Instead just post sample data with code.

Comment: I just add the picture of my sample data

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't post data in images.It would be difficult to replicate the problem. check out this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: ok. sorry, i was confused about posting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you are passing the float value to your classifier which expects categorical values as target vector.Try using the regressor algorithms.
i.e instead of **RandomForestClassifier** you should use [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) for continuous target vector.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. It works! but if i want to implement the other classifier such as MLP classifier, logistic regression or SVM, how should i arrange the data?

Comment: For classifiers, convert your target vector in categorical form. Check out this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html. Other than that it fully depends on data and other measuring parameters to figure out the best suited model.